# Set symmetric specific cuts for bimodal data

Tags: r, histogram, subset

I have a binomial assymetric distribution which I would like to cut at both ends. The specific part of it is that I would like to calculate symmetric boundaries at the appropriate side of each 'bell'. The figure shows an extreme case of separation between bells for simplicity.

[image]

In this case the red cuts were selected by eye and the 1550 blue lines used at each side represent an arbitrary value that could potentially be passed through a function for the trim. My goal would be subset everything between blue lines.

```
hist(p3_cut$x,50)
abline(v=c(6200,7600),col='red')
abline(v=c(6200-1500,7600+1500),col='blue')
```

My guess is that the problem here is basically find the 'edges' of each curve. I cannot use half distance between means, I need something that recognizes frequency change from 0 (or very low value) to something relatively high.

Comment: You can get a binned version of your variable with `binned_x <- cut(p3_cut$x, 50)`, and get the difference in counts between consecutive bins with `diff(table(binned_x))`. You can then find the max/min of that diff vector to find biggest changes in frequency.

Comment: I like the approach but the bin=50 was known, how to solve that without a known 'perfect' binning for that? Also, what if max changes are between the first cut and the second instead of the zero frequency and the first cut??

Comment: @PhilippeMarchand Just as an example if I change the bin = 50 gives me max(diff(table(binned_x))) = 103 and the same thing with bin = 10 gives me 243. Also, as you can see in the graph the change for the second curve would be max in between the first and second bin and not between the 0 and first bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat general answer. Depending on the problem you might need to adjust the binwidth in the density function:

```
# get density of x and normalize so max is one
dens <- density(x,adjust=0.1)
dens$y <- dens$y / max(dens$y)

# keep all x where density is higher than some fraction of max (here 1%)
min_frac <- 0.01
x_keep <- dens$x[dens$y > 0.01]

# find position of gap in x, and get x just before and after gap
gap_pos <- which.max(diff(x_keep))
left_cut <- x_keep[gap_pos]
right_cut <- x_keep[gap_pos + 1]
```

Using this code and changing the adjust parameter in the `density` function I was able to calculate almost perfect cuts at least for this case. I am positive that this approach is flexible enough for most situations that are similar to this one. I show the results for the cuts proposed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is good enough for finding the points, it needs changing the dens$y > threshold for the problem but it's good enough because it also allows flexibility